# Is this always true that if the angle in degrees is negative, its radian counterpart will also be negative and vice-versa?

Tags: trigonometry

I want to know : if the angle in degrees is negative, will its radian counterpart will also be negative, or can it be anything(positive/negative)?

I know that 180 degrees = pi radians.
but, does -180 degrees = -pi radians? Isn't pi just a measurement?

Comment: The sign only tells you the direction in which the angle is measured. The direction does not depend on the units used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. As you noted, the conversion from radians to degrees is just multiplication by a positive constant, so they will always have the same sign. But in many cases, the angle $\theta$ acts the same as $\theta+360^\circ $, so in this case, a positive radian amount might act the same as a negative degree amount.